# Firebase Storage component is not present

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

trying to implement firebase storage in my Flutter project but wahtever I do with **StorageReference** I'm getting "Firebase Storage component is not present" error any suggestions ?

using:

> firebase_storage: ^3.0.1

in dependecies in pubspec file 
- maybe worth to mention : in my project I'm using firestore and firebase Auth and thoes work without any issues

Comment: try running `flutter get packages` and see if there is an error, if not try to change the firebase_storage version

Comment: @Networker hi, tryed v. 3.0.0 and 3.0.1 and ofc I run get Packages - no help though:S

Comment: Have you tried to run flutter clean, and run the app again?

Comment: @GabrielMoreyra no, will try it as soon I'm back home from work and will let You know, ty